# Why does my react/webpack app refresh when I click on a link?

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack

I have a `react` app that I am using `webpack` to build in `chunks`.  I am serving everything up with an `express` server.  When I click on a `link`, I want the `script` tag to be added to the `index.html`.  I am expecting this to download the file and not refresh the page.

Here is my `server.js`:

```
app.use(express.static('./dist'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Listening on 3000");
}
```

Here is my `webpack.config`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './App.js',
        vendors: vendors
    },
    output: {
        filename: './bundle.[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: './[id].[hash].js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'index.ejs'
            }),

        new CommonsPlugin({
            name: 'vendors',
            filename: 'vendors.js',
            minChunks: Infinity
        })
    ]
};
```

Here is the `App.js` where everything starts at:

```
const rootRoute = {
    component: 'div',
    childRoutes: [ {
        path: '/',
        component: Main,
        childRoutes: [
            require('./routes/reports')
        ]
    } ]
};

render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={rootRoute} />, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Finally here in my `Main.js` component that has the link:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <Link href="/reports">Reports</Link>
                    <div>
                        {this.props.children || <Home /> }
                    </div>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

The page works, but when I click on the `reports` link in the `Main`, my page refreshes instead of just inserting the new code.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is `routes/reports'

```
module.exports = {
    path: 'reports',
    getComponents(location, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
            cb(null, require('./components/Reports'))
        })
    }
}
```

And the `Reports` component:

```
class Reports extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Reports</h2>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = Reports;
```

Comment: The line `require('./routes/reports')`. What does that look like? A possible reason your page is refreshing is because the `/reports` url does not match to anything in your router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
<Link href="/reports">Reports</Link>
```

Do

```
<Link to="/reports">Reports</Link>
```

Comment: What is the difference between the 2?  Doesn't `to` just create an `href`?

Comment: I reviewed react-router's source code. If you simply pass `href` instead of `to`, it will only be a simple anchor and won't pass [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/modules/Link.js#L97) which won't do the `pushState` in your case (e.g. there won't be any javascript managing the history on your anchor)